# Twilio Two different Voice REQUEST URL for inbound call and Twilio Device Client?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I had call tracking set up on my system following this tutorial https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/call-tracking-php-laravel, i have created twiML app with Voice REQUEST URL configured for this call tracking purpose. 
Basically on my system i have list of users with their own personal number and assigned twilio number so whenever call comes in to one of twilio numbers, twilio posts to Voice REQUEST URL and in that url i have logic for call forwarding to their personal number, recording call log etc.This is working fine.

Now my new requirement is ability to call through browser to any number, I read this tutorial https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/browser-calls-php-laravel . It seems i need to use Twilio Device Client.

My question is it fine to create new different twiML app for this purpose so that i will have separate Voice REQUEST URL where i can put apporiate logic to call destination number OR i should use same twiML app and within same REQUEST URL of my system i need to put logic for two different purposes? what could be recommended way of doing this?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Answer (score 2):

"create new different twiML app for this purpose so that i will have separate Voice REQUEST URL where i can put apporiate logic to call destination number"
Your first answer seems the best. Keeps your code and logic cleaner.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, by the way any caveat for using multiple twiml app?

Comment: It seems i need to reassign all existing twilio numbers to this new app as well

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. There are no caveats or problems for using multiple TwiML apps, this is definitely what you want to do in this situation.